# In Dojo, is it safer to use this.own, or is attach-event safe, too?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I can choose between two ways of attaching an event to a dijit. I can attach an event using data-dojo-attach-event:

```
<div data-dojo-attach-event="onclick: _onClick"></div>
```

Or, I can attach an event using this.own:

```
this.own(
    on(this.someNode, 'click', '_onClick')
)
```

With respect to cleaning up event handlers, which is safer? I know that this.own will cleanup the handles when the dijit is destroyed, but will attach-event cleanup handles when the dijit is destroyed?

EDIT: Forgot to add this case. Will this handler be cleaned up when the parent dijit is destroyed?

```
var aButton = new Button({
    label: 'Click Me',
    onClick: function () {
        console.log('i am a handler, too!');
    }
}, domConstruct.create('div', {} this.domNode));
```

Comment: Don't forget to use "click" instead of "onclick" (will not work) for data-dojo-attach-event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of the source code, handlers attached by the `data-dojo-attach-event` are added to an `_attachEvents` array that gets iterated over and remove is called during the `destroyRendering` phase. So, either should be safe.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed that both are safe... but I would opt for using

```
on(this.someNode, 'click', '_onClick')
```

in the event that you need to change the scope of this. I've found many times, especially with buttons, i'll want to call other functions within my dijit instead of having access to just the button. In this case you can do

```
on(this.someNode, 'click', lang.hitch(this, this._onClick));
```

and most of the time get what you need from the event object. More info here:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html#hitch

Comment: Thanks, Kyle. I omitted the lang.hitch for brevity. But, it's so common that I can't think of a time were I HAVE NOT used it. Also worth noting that data-dojo-attach-event scopes to *this* too.

Comment: Kyle, FYI, lang.hitch will take a string as the second argument and look for  a method with the same name on the object in the first argument, so you could write your call:

on(this.someNode, 'click', lang.hitch(this, "_onClick"));